# Gibt es eine vollständige Liste von Adjektiven, die einen Umlaut im Komparativ und Superlativ haben?

Tags: adjective, declension, umlaut

Gibt es eine Liste mit **allen** Komparationen, die eine Umlaut im Komparativ und Superlativ kriegen?

Ich habe nur diese gefunden:

```
warm     wärmer    am wärmsten
klug     klüger    am klügsten
arm      ärmer     am ärmsten
grob     gröber    am gröbsten
schwach  schwächer am schwächsten
jung     jünger    am jüngsten
dumm     dümmer    am dümmsten
```

*Aber das passt nicht! Eine Sprache, die von 80 Millionen Leuten gesprochen wird, sollte mehr unregelmäßige Steigerungen in den Komparationen haben..... oder nicht?*

Comment: Was hat die Anzahl der Muttersprachler mit der Anzahl der regelmäßigen Adjektive zu tun? (Außerdem sind es mindestens 95 Millionen.)

Comment: +520 Millionen Menschen haben Spanisch als Mutterprache und wir haben kaum unregelmäßige Steigerungen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Abgesehen von einigen zusammengesetzten Adjektiven, die sich analog zum Stammadjektiv verhalten (z. B. *wasserarm),* werden im Deutschen meines Wissens nur primäre Adjektive¹ mit Umlautung gesteigert. Von diesen gibt es nur etwa dreihundert (was auch relativ normal für eine Sprache sein dürfte). Davon wiederum enthält nur etwa die Hälfte einen umlautbaren Laut und ist steigerbar. Und auch nicht alle diese Adjektive werden mit Umlautung gesteigert. Damit ist die Menge der mit Umlaut gesteigerten Adjektive tatsächlich sehr gering.

Ich habe mir nun die [Adjektivliste des Wiktionarys](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Adjektive#Voll_steigerungs-_und_deklinationsf.C3.A4hig) geschnappt und bin sie per Hand durchgegangen. Es verblieben 32 Stück:

> alt, arg, arm, (bange), (blass), dumm, (fromm), (gesund), (glatt), grob, groß, [gut], hart, hoch, jung, kalt, (karg), klug, krank, (krumm), kurz, lang, nah, (nass), (rot), scharf, (schmal), schwach, schwarz, stark, [viel], warm

Dabei kennzeichnen runde Klammern Adjektive, die sowohl mit als auch ohne Umlaut gesteigert werden können, und eckige Klammern völlig unregelmäßige Adjektive.

---

<sup>¹ Adjektive, die weder entlehnt (z. B. *fair, rosa)* noch abgeleitet sind (z. B. *lesbar, hölzern, klebrig*).</sup>