# Is there any list of irregular adjectives in German on the web? (not suiting adjective to the Adjektivdeklination)

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

Is there any list of irregular adjectives that don't suit the Adjektivdeklination chart(rules)? (My question is not about Komparativ and Superlativ adjective forms)

Comment: Related: [Gibt es eine vollständige Liste von Adjektiven, die einen Umlaut im Komparativ und Superlativ haben?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/20762/2594) and [Adjectives that don't require adjective endings](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9264/2594)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are surprisingly few irregular German adjectives, but there are some. First, *gut* has irregular comparatives: *besser* and *besten*. Others such as *stark* add an umlaut in comparatives. One adjective, *hoch*, has an irregular attributive form *hoh-*. I don't know if that's the only one of that type, and it's not much of a change. The declension rules work for *hoh-*, you just start with a different stem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I was only asking about Adjektivdeklination rules(putting suffixes end of the adjective according to article)(not about Komparativ and Superlativ forms).

Comment: @Sukru Araci: I mentioned attributive forms in the second half of my answer. Declension covers a lot of ground, but I think I touched on everything.

Comment: Oh, I've now realized. Thank you very much, I wish it is the only exception in rules :)

Comment: By the way, is there any list on the web for adjectives that is irregular ones like your example "hoch". (I've found for Komparativ and Superlativ but I couldn't find for Adjektivdeklination.)

Comment: @Sukru Araci: I don't know if there is a list, or even if *hoch* is the only adjective that would be on it. Some adjectives lose an extra *-e-* in the stem, but I don't count that as 'truly' irregular. An example is *böse* which declines as *böser*, *böse*, *böses*, etc. The [etymology section in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoch#Etymology_2) seems to imply that *hoch* is the only irregular in Modern German, but it's not very explicit.

Comment: Thank you so much. (Then, If I start to learn German adjectives according to the Adjective declination chart, Finally, I'll have known almost whole of the adjectives except very few word. Am I right?)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the superlative of _hoch_ is _höchst_, so the claim "The declension rules work for _hoh-_, you just start with a different stem." is not fully correct.

Comment: @Jonathan Scholbach: I was thinking about declining with respect to gender, case, and article. But your right, it's also irregular in comparisons: *hoch*, *höher*, *höchst*.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing answer, there are also some invariant adjectives in German. Those adjectives always have the same form. Some adjectives are really nouns, for example "extra", "klasse", "scheiße", "1a" (all of them colloquial), some are prefixes like "trans", "hetero", "cis". Since those two classes of words can be put before a noun, they work like adjectives. As they are consired adjectives, they are written separately and in lower case. For example:

> ein klasse Stürmer, ein cis Mann, ihr Stürmer ist klasse

Another class of invariant adjectives is formed of colors. The colors "lila" and "rosa" are also invariant.

> ein rosa Stift, ein lila Papier

In colloquial speech, they sometimes are declined normally. To break hiatus, an "n" is inserted:

> ein rosaner Stift, ein lilanes Papier

See also the [linked question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/adjectives-that-dont-require-adjective-endings) about invariant adjectives.

Comment: Then, I will have to learn the constant adjectives first. Thank you.

Comment: Many, if not most uninflected adjectives are easily recognizable by their non-standard ending. This applies to *rosa*, *lila*, *prima*.

Comment: It should be noted that the usage of cis/trans is still in flux. So "ein trans Mann", "ein Trans Mann" und "ein Transmann" can all be seen.